# Converting pointer of class A to class B in function return, when B has constructor with `A*`

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

In C++, can we return a pointer of `A` from a function whose actual return value is a different struct `B` which indeed has the first object as the pointer of `A`?

Consider the following scenario.

```cpp
struct B {
    A* ptr;
    // code...

    B(A* _ptr)
    {
        // code...
    }

};

B foo()
{
    A* tmp;
    // code...
    return tmp;
}

B bar()
{
    A* tmp;
    // code...
    return B(tmp);
}
```

Will the `foo()` method work correctly? Will it be able to call the constructor?

Or `foo()` will not be able to call the constructor and it works only in the case when B was defined in the following way,

```cpp
struct B {
    A* ptr;
    // code...

    B(A* _ptr) : ptr(_ptr)
    {
        // some code (doesn't changes `ptr`)
    }

};
```

OR in the following way

```cpp
struct B {
    A* ptr; // NO more data elements other than `ptr`

    B (A* _ptr) : ptr(_ptr) {
        // some code (doesn't changes `ptr`)
    }
};
```

If it works, is it because `A* ptr` in `B` comes as the first object?

I'd like to know what are the possibilities for this on different C++ versions (<11, 11, 14, 17) or if it also depends on the compiler I use.

I suppose, `bar` is the best way to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's test it!

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct A;

struct B {
    B(A* _ptr)
    {
        std::cout << "I've been called!" << std::endl;
    }

};

B foo()
{
    A* tmp;
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of such simple program is:

```
I've been called!
```

Meaning that constructor has been called.

It's possible, because `B (A* _ptr)` is a conversion constructor. This type of constructor allows automatic conversion to the class being constructed.

---

Just as @john mentioned, to disable this behaviour we use `explicit` specifier.

`explicit B(A*)` and `foo()` is no longer accepted.

---

Additionally, as you can see, in my version of `B`, there is no member `A* ptr;` - it isn't required.

Comment: To be fair testing it would only answer the question for one particular compiler.

Comment: I wasn't aware of automatic conversions. Of course, I tested before posting this up but I was doubtful if it's compiler-specific or C++ version specific. 
At least I came to know about the concept rather than just knowing if it works or not.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comment as well. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Further to what Jorengarenar said. Sometimes you want to disable this behaviour. This is what the `explicit` keyword does

```
#include <iostream>

struct A;

struct B {
    explicit B(A* _ptr)
    {
        std::cout << "I've been called!" << std::endl;
    }

};

B foo()
{
    A* tmp;
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

This version no longer compiles. `return tmp;` is an error but `return B(tmp);` would compile and call the constructor.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot!